# How can I use a hard disk from Mac with ownCloud?

Tags: raspbian, usb, hard-drive, file-sharing, owncloud

I have a hard drive that is formatted for use with my Macbook Pro. I would like to, without formatting the hard drive, use this hard drive on owncloud so I can access the files away from home. The size of the hard drive is 3TB. I already have ownCloud up and running. Can I use this HDD with ownCloud? Will ownCloud recognize the files/folders?

I mainly have video files that I want to be able to download onto my Mac and watch while on vacation.

There is a spare 1TB that I can use if necessary, but how can I get the files I want to share from the 3TB HDD to the 1TB HDD and have ownCloud share them?

Comment: Linux can read HFS filesystems - which is what Macs use IIRC. I've never used Owncloud so I don't know what sort of permissions Owncloud needs to have a shared drive. If it were me, I'd use the 1TB drive to share everything.

Answer (score 1):

You'll want to make sure you have hfs installed

```
sudo apt-get install hfsplus hfsutils hfsprogs
```

Plug the drive into the pi and then verify that the pi can see the file system by first identifying the drive with:

```
sudo fdisk -l
```

Then fscking it with

```
fsck.hfsplus -f /dev/sdaN
```

Where N would be the found in the fdisk list

Then mount with

```
mount -o force /dev/sdN /mnt/somewhere/owncloud/can/use
```

You may need to fiddle with the permission and mount locations for owncloud, but this should be ok for attaching the drive.